# Download file in Meteor Cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I made a Meteor "desktop" application and I'm currently migrating it into an "android" one. No big deal, even if I'm completely new to Cordova, everything works perfectly except one thing : I cannot download files.

The application provides files to download like pdf reports, csv archives or even JSON raw files (I use the [nilsdannemann:pdfmake](https://github.com/NilsDannemann/meteor-pdfmake/) package or [pfafman:filesaver](https://github.com/pfafman/meteor-filesaver/)).

I tried to run my application on Chrome (on a Android device) and everything works fine. But when I use Cordova `meteor run android-device` none of these download functions work anymore.

I search how to create file to download with Cordova and I found some topic saying it's not supported. If you could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: In cordova you can directly write to the filesystem, so why not just do that? (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file) You can find an example of that in our open-source typhone app: https://github.com/chfritz/typhone/blob/master/app/client/main.js#L179

Comment: Okay it's totally what I'm looking for, thanks for the help.